# Why I failed to install pgadmin?

Tags: apt, pgadmin

I try to install pgadmin under ubuntu 20.04 reading article at https://linuxhint.com/best_gui_clients_postgresql_ubuntu/

but after some attempts I got error message :

```
hoster@hoster-os:~/Downloads$ sudo apt update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I check content of the file mentioned below :

```
hoster@hoster-os:~/Downloads$ cat  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list 
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/
focal-pgdg main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/
focal-pgdg main
```

i have :

```
lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
5.15.0-41-generic
x86_64
```

Which is the correct way to fix error and install pgadmin ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` file is not correctly formatted; there is no release field after the URL, likely because you have added a `\n` making the subsequent fields appear on the next entry resulting in an error on line 2 also, however processing stops at the first line with an error.  (*this advice assumes you're using 20.04 & not 20*)

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. How can I fix it ? Can I delete file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.lis and rearun commands one more time ?